# How to expand and collapse, depending on whether a property is in an array

Tags: angular

I have a problem when I try to collapse or expand a div, the idea is to see if there is a propeity within an array to see if it expands or collapse, but when I do the ngClass to verify, the class is never added.

Currently my code is as follows, the propeities are added as corresponds to the array.

```
  public expandRefresh(gameDate){

    if(!this.gamesRefresh.includes(gameDate)){
      this.gamesRefresh.push(gameDate);
    }
    else{
      this.gamesRefresh = this.gamesRefresh.filter( date => date !== gameDate);
    }

  }
```

and a part of the HTML of the code is the following

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let dateGroup of gamesOffering.DateGrouping">
            <div #collapseall class="offering-games-wrapper" id="expandcollapse" collapsed="false" [ngClass]='{"collapsed": gamesRefresh.includes(dateGroup.GameDate) ? true : false}'>
                <div class="offering-games-header-table-date">
                    <span class="offering-games-desktop-date bigger-text">{{dateGroup.GameDate  | date : 'fullDate'}}</span>
                    <span class="offering-games-mobile-date bigger-text">{{dateGroup.GameDate  | date : 'MMM, dd'}}</span>
                    <div class="offering-games-header-table-collapse" (click)="expandRefresh(dateGroup.GameDate)">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Just offhand, id="expandcollapse" is bad. You can't have multiple elements with the same name. In fact, most the time you don't need it at all.

This could cause that problem, without even looking at the rest of the code

Comment: that's an old implementation, if this works I'm going to remove those ids, it's used to expand or collapse all the elements together

Comment: If that's what it's for... It's still wrong! IDs per the HTML specs *must be unique* . If the page works as expected, it's by chance and not design.

Comment: is `dateGroup` in your `ngFor `& dateGroup.GameDate is objects ?

Comment: yes, GameDate is a property of DateGrouping, declared in its model.

Comment: what i mean it the type of `GameDate` value and `dateGroup`, is it `string` or ` `DateTime object` ?

Comment: oh sorry, GameDate is string property of dateGroup wich is a object.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a value (eg: true or false) from your function expandRefresh()

Comment: expandRefresh () is only used to add or remove an element from the array, I do not understand why it would need to return something

Comment: @PCH Ideally it would, or would at least always return the same type. This to me is a code smell, but seeing as you use a ternary operator for the actual ngClass, I don't believe this is the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are checking if an object is exist in an array of object. It is important to know that the `includes()` function is **finding** the `object` **reference** that matched, not the `object`'s **properties** that matched:

```
const dummyArray = [{1: 2}];
const dummyObject = {1: 2};
dummyArray.incluces(dummyObject) // return: false

//Same with Date object

const dateArr = [new Date('July 16, 2019')];
const dateObj = new Date('July 16, 2019');
dateArr.includes(dateObj) // return: false
```

And because of that, you should find if that object exist based on one of it's `property`. Im using `find()` function for this.

```
  gamesRefresh.find( x => x.getTime() == dateGroup.GameDate.getTime()) ? true : false
```